# I cannot figure out how to fix an unhandled Format Excpetion

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to write a C# program using Visual Studio that reads data from a file and allow me perform various sorts on the data. I am a beginner so it took much research to figure out how to write this code: Now I get a:

> Format Exception was unhandled.  Input string was not in a correct
>   format

I am not sure where I went wrong. This is happening for the following line of code:

`Candidate newrec = new Candidate(str[0], str[1], str [2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], Convert.ToInt32(str[7]), str[8], str[9], str[10], str[11]);`

The entire code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;



namespace Unit4IP
{
   //used to sort in asceding and descending order
    public struct Candidate:IComparable 
    {

       public char[] _FirstName;
        public char[] _LastName;
        public char[] _Company;
        public char[] _Address;
        public char[] _City;
        public char[] _Country;
        public char[] _State;
        public char[] _Phone;
        public char[] _Fax;
        public char[] _Email;
        public char[] _Web;
        public int _zip;

        //for comparing objects
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Candidate Candidate2 = (Candidate)obj;
            return _LastName.ToString().CompareTo(Candidate2._LastName.ToString());
        }
        //implements sorting based on assignments such as zip, lastname, etc. 
        public int CompareTo(Candidate Candidate2,
            CandidateComparer.ComparisonType comptype)
        {
            if(comptype==CandidateComparer.ComparisonType.Lastname)
            {
                    String _LName = new String(_LastName);
                    String LName = new String(Candidate2._LastName);
                    return _LName.CompareTo(LName);// Convert Character Array to String because CompareTo Works efficiently with Strings
            }
            else
            {
                    return Candidate2._zip.CompareTo(_zip); // compareto values that are interchanged in descending order
            }
        }
               //Constructor of Candidate Structure
         public Candidate(string FirstName, string LastName, string Company, string Address, string City, string Country, string State, int zip, string Phone, string Fax, string Email, string Web)
        {
            _FirstName = new char[12];
            _LastName = new char[16];
            _Company = new char[32];
            _Address = new char[32];
            _City = new char[24];
            _Country = new char[24];
            _State = new char[2];
            _Phone = new char[12];
            _Fax = new char[12];
            _Email = new char[32];
            _Web = new char[42];
            _FirstName = FirstName.ToCharArray();
            _LastName = LastName.ToCharArray();
            _Company = Company.ToCharArray();
            _Address = Address.ToCharArray();
            _City = City.ToCharArray();
            _Country = Country.ToCharArray();
            _State = State.ToCharArray();
            _zip = zip;
            _Phone = Phone.ToCharArray();
            _Fax = Fax.ToCharArray();
            _Email = Email.ToCharArray();
            _Web = Web.ToCharArray();
        }

         //Implement IComparer Interface as nested structure
         public struct CandidateComparer : IComparer
         {
             public enum ComparisonType
             { Lastname = 1, zip = 2 }
             private ComparisonType _comparisonType;
             public ComparisonType comptype
             {
                 get { return _comparisonType; }
                 set { _comparisonType = value; }
             }
             public int Compare(object x, object y)
             {
                 Candidate Candidate1 = (Candidate)x;
                 Candidate Candidate2 = (Candidate)y;

                 return Candidate1.CompareTo(Candidate2, _comparisonType);
             }
         }
    }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList ArrayTest = new ArrayList();
            //Loading of File 'ITCO321_U4_sample_data.csv' into ArraList. File only holds values, no heading i.e. remove headings
            StreamReader stream1 = File.OpenText("c:\\Users\\Cdhss\\Documents\\ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data-2.csv");
            string recdata = null;
            while ((recdata = stream1.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] str = recdata.Split(',');
                Candidate newrec = new Candidate(str[0], str[1], str [2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], Convert.ToInt32(str[7]), str[8], str[9], str[10], str[11]);
                ArrayTest.Add(newrec);//add struct object into ArrayList
            }
                        //Traversing of Records
            Console.WriteLine("Traversing Records");
            foreach (Candidate Candidate1 in ArrayTest)
            {
                string fname = new String(Candidate1._FirstName);
                string lname=new String(Candidate1._LastName);
                string company = new String(Candidate1._Company);
                string address=new String(Candidate1._Address);
                string city=new String(Candidate1._City);
                string country = new String(Candidate1._Country);
                string phone = new String(Candidate1._Phone);
                string fax = new String(Candidate1._Fax);
                string email=new String(Candidate1._Email);
                string web = new String(Candidate1._Web);
                Console.WriteLine( fname + "," + lname + "," + company + "," + address  + "," + city + "," + country + "," + Candidate1._zip + "," + phone + "," + fax + "," + email + "," + web);
            }
            Candidate.CandidateComparer comparer = new Candidate.CandidateComparer();
            //Sort by Lastname in ascending order
            comparer.comptype = Candidate.CandidateComparer.ComparisonType.Lastname;
            ArrayTest.Sort(comparer);
            Console.WriteLine("Sorting of Elements by LastName");
            foreach (Candidate Candidate1 in ArrayTest)
            {
                string fname = new String(Candidate1._FirstName);
                string lname = new String(Candidate1._LastName);
                string company = new String(Candidate1._Company);
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + fname + "," + lname + "," + company);
            }
            // Data sorted in desending order of ZIP field
            comparer.comptype = Candidate.CandidateComparer.ComparisonType.zip;
            ArrayTest.Sort(comparer);
            Console.WriteLine("Sorting of Elements by Zip");
            foreach (Candidate Candidate1 in ArrayTest)
            {
                string fname = new String(Candidate1._FirstName);
                string lname = new String(Candidate1._LastName);
                string company = new String(Candidate1._Company);
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + fname + "," + lname + "," + company + "," + Candidate1._zip);
            }

            //Display Records of 'NY' State
            Console.WriteLine("Display Records of NY State");
            foreach (Candidate Candidate1 in ArrayTest)
            {
                string fname = new String(Candidate1._FirstName);
                string lname = new String(Candidate1._LastName);
                string company = new String(Candidate1._Company);
                string address = new String(Candidate1._Address);
                string city = new String(Candidate1._City);
                string country = new String(Candidate1._Country);
                string phone = new String(Candidate1._Phone);
                string fax = new String(Candidate1._Fax);
                string email = new String(Candidate1._Email);
                string web = new String(Candidate1._Web);
                if (new String(Candidate1._State).Contains("NY"))
                    Console.WriteLine(fname + "," + lname + "," + company + "," + address + "," + city + "," + country + "," + Candidate1._zip + "," + phone + "," + fax + "," + email + "," + web);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the file you're reading

Comment: BTW: put all your properties(firstname,lastname etc.) to a class and keep an array of it.

Comment: Obviously, `str[7]` did not hold a valid integer value at some point. Write the values to console to see what they really are.

Comment: The file is too long however it is a data file with the following 12 headings :     FirstName LastName Company Address City County State ZIP Phone Fax Email Web Convert to Pig Latin

Comment: you must learn how to use debug in .Net then see the value of `str[7]`. post value here so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your call to Convert.ToInt32. Whatever string you are passing can't be parsed as an int.

A good solution here might be to use the some structured exception handling, either with try catch blocks or Int32.TryParse(string) for example you could do this

```
int intValue;
if (Int32.TryParse(str[7], out intValue)) 
{
     //Do some thing with the int value
}
else
{
     throw new Exception("Some informative error message, probably using string.Format to include the string you tried to parse");
}
```

TryParse returns true if the parse is successfull, false if it is not, and puts the parsed integer value in the second out parameter.

A few other comments on you code to help you out.

1. No one uses ArrayLists in C# anymore. Generics were introduced a long time ago, and it is almost always better, from a standpoint of both type safety and speed to use a List (Look up C# generics if you don't know what they are).
2. You don't need to copy the candidate properties in your foreach loop into new variables.
3. Give more informative variable names. Readability is the single most important quality in good code. fname should be firstName, recdata should be recievedData. Key strokes are cheap in a world with tab completion.